# Using Zapier to get FireStore sub-collection ID's

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm using Zapier to look up user information in FireStore based on the user's email address. I have a Top Collection called "groups" which contain users. If I use the attached query in Zapier and hard code the {GROUP_ID}, so that the path is "groups/{GROUP_ID}/users", then the query works.

Successful Zapier Structured Firestore Query
[image]

However, I won't know the GROUP_ID at the time of the query. I'm thinking I'll need to loop through all groups (since google's collection groups don't appear to be supported in Zapier). But in order to loop through the groups, I first need to get a list of all the GROUP_ID's.

Because the GROUP_ID's are the top level sub-collection, I can't seem to figure out how to get Zapier to return a list of all of them. Zapier requires that I specify a collection group (groups) and a field path, and cannot leave either blank.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!